# How to create a jquery object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have city object in my project. I want to create a jquery array with some city objects. I can take city list from .ashx file and create single city objects. But I couldn't push them to an array. Here is my code:

```
 var postDataCity = { funcName: "GetCities" };

        var cities = [];
        var city = {};

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "KurumInformation.ashx",
            data: postDataCity,
            async: true,
            success: function (msg) {
                $.each(msg, function (i, v) {
                    city.M_CityId = this.M_CityId ;
                    city.M_CityName= this.M_CityName;
                    cities.push(city);
                });
            },
            error: function (d) {
                alert('error :' + d);
            },
        });

        console.log(cities);
```

After this I check cities but there is an error I think because I can't see cities in console. Where is my mistake?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: It's **asynchronous**, the console.log executes before the array is populated, as that's the way ajax works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost fine, you have to declare the `city` inside the loop.

Also you have just to move the `console.log` after the pushing to see the results:

```
success: function (msg) {
    $.each(msg, function (i, v) {
        var city = {};   //Move declaration here
        city.M_CityId = this.M_CityId ;
        city.M_CityName= this.M_CityName;
        cities.push(city);
    });
    console.log(cities);   //Move it here
},
```

If you declare it outside, you'll be adding to the array the same city reference each time.

Also, as the ajax call is asynchronous, your old `console.log` executed before the ajax call finished, that's why you saw empty results.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(msg, function (i, v) {
       city.M_CityId = v.M_CityId ;
       city.M_CityName= v.M_CityName;
       cities.push(city);
});
```

It will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

You display the variable before the callback of the AJAX call is made. You should have your console.log() inside the callback.